# Interpolating Month rows to Day rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

"""SO."""
I have data for a store's revenue each month. How do I create daily rows for each month?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-02-01',
        '2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-03-01','2019-03-01','2019-03-01'],
    'Company': ['Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C', 'Store A', 'Store B', 
        'Store C','Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C'],
    'Monthly Revenue': [200, 800, 400, 400, 300, 600, 400, 400, 900]
})

print(df)

         date  Company  Monthly Revenue
0  2019-01-01  Store A              200
1  2019-01-01  Store B              800
2  2019-01-01  Store C              400
3  2019-02-01  Store A              400
4  2019-02-01  Store B              300
5  2019-02-01  Store C              600
6  2019-03-01  Store A              400
7  2019-03-01  Store B              400
8  2019-03-01  Store C              900
```

Desired Result:

```
         date  Company  Monthly Revenue
0  2019-01-01  Store A              200
1  2019-01-02  Store A              200
2  2019-01-03  Store A              200
3  2019-01-04  Store A              200
........
30  2019-01-31 Store A              200
31  2019-02-01 Store A              400
32  2019-02-02 Store A              400
32  2019-02-03 Store A              400
```

Notice each month has a specific number of days. All of my data is monthly through January to December, so the correct number of daily rows must match the number of days in a month (31 rows for Jan, 28 rows in Feb, 31 rows in March, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `date` column begins with first day of the month for each Store, you could do `.pivot_table()` and then reample with `.ffill()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-01','2019-02-01',
                           '2019-03-01','2019-03-01','2019-03-01'],
                   'Company': ['Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C', 'Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C',
                              'Store A', 'Store B', 'Store C'],
                   'Monthly Revenue': [200, 800, 400, 400, 300, 600, 400, 400, 900]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df['date'],  df['date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)]), columns=['date']).combine_first(df)
df = df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='Company').resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              date Monthly Revenue                
Company                    Store A Store B Store C
0       2019-01-01           200.0   800.0   400.0
1       2019-01-02           200.0   800.0   400.0
2       2019-01-03           200.0   800.0   400.0
3       2019-01-04           200.0   800.0   400.0
4       2019-01-05           200.0   800.0   400.0
..             ...             ...     ...     ...
85      2019-03-27           400.0   400.0   900.0
86      2019-03-28           400.0   400.0   900.0
87      2019-03-29           400.0   400.0   900.0
88      2019-03-30           400.0   400.0   900.0
89      2019-03-31           400.0   400.0   900.0

[90 rows x 4 columns]
```

If you need it in one row, you could do additionally:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='date')
print(df[['date', 'Company', 'value']])
```

This prints:

```
          date  Company  value
0   2019-01-01  Store A  200.0
1   2019-01-02  Store A  200.0
2   2019-01-03  Store A  200.0
3   2019-01-04  Store A  200.0
4   2019-01-05  Store A  200.0
..         ...      ...    ...
265 2019-03-27  Store C  900.0
266 2019-03-28  Store C  900.0
267 2019-03-29  Store C  900.0
268 2019-03-30  Store C  900.0
269 2019-03-31  Store C  900.0

[270 rows x 3 columns]
```